# AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'SPA'

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, cross-domain, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to make a request for a token request to an API service running on the Azure platform. I solved the cross origin problem with proxy pass setting via Plesk, but when the request is forwarded, I get the following error and there is no solution.

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS9002326:
> Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page
> Application' client-type.\r\nTrace ID:
> 578a738f-3b77-4a4b-a425-160f38da2d00\r\nCorrelation ID:
> cabc0d01-da8d-4b44-90b8-b182c1f21e1b\r\nTimestamp: 2022-07-03
> 18:51:58Z","error_codes":[9002326],"timestamp":"2022-07-03
> 18:51:58Z","trace_id":"578a738f-3b77-4a4b-a425-160f38da2d00","correlation_id":"cabc0d01-da8d-4b44-90b8-b182c1f21e1b","error_uri":"https://login.windows.net/error?code=9002326"}

***My Nginx Proxy pass Settings***

```
location /vipps/ {
    proxy_pass https://apitest.vipps.no/;
}

underscores_in_headers on;
```

Request needs that headers

1. client_id
2. client_secret
3. Vipps-Subscription-Key
4. Merchant-Serial-Number

When I forward this problem to the vipps authority, it says you have the problem, but as far as I researched, it is related to the Azure platform.

Answer (score 0):

- As per this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#configure-platform-settings),

> Select **Single-page application** platform if you're building a client-side web app by using JavaScript or a framework like Angular, Vue.js, React.js, or Blazor WebAssembly.

***Redirect URI for SPA:***
[image]

- As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redirect-uri-setup-required-for-single-page-apps) ,

> The authorization code flow for single page applications requires additional setup. Follow the instructions for [creating your single-page application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-20-with-auth-code-flow) to correctly mark your redirect URI as enabled for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Please refer [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315313/azure-app-registration-causing-the-following-error.html) for more information.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to connect to Vipps api with spa. I am not authorized to control the backend side of the Vipps application. How can I fix this problem by FrontEnd?